# How to print SQL results in HTML tables?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would need some help on how to print SQL search results in HTML table (yes, I know it's not the best choice and I will improve that later) with links.

This is how my code looks now:

```
$databaseconnection=mysql_CONNECT("here is my usernames etc")
or die("Can't get access to the database");

mysql_select_db("username")
or die ("can't find the database");
$sentence="SELECT `name`, `country`, `sex`, `color`, `pattern`, `coat`, `breeder` FROM `database` WHERE `name` = '$name' or `country` = '$country' or `sex` = '$sex' or `color` = '$color' or `pattern` = '$pattern' or `coat` = '$coat' or `breeder` = '$breeder'";

$result=mysql_query($sentence,$databaseconnection) or die ("Couldn't save tha information").mysql_error();

echo "<table>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<tr><td><a href=" . $row['name']> print $row['name'] . "</a>". "</td><td>" . $row['country'] . "</td></tr>". "</td><td>" . $row['sex']. "</td><td>" . $row['color']. "</td><td>". "</td><td>" . $row['pattern'] . $row['coat']. "</td><td>" . $row['breeders'];
}

echo "</td></table>";

mysql_close();
```

What I'm doing wrong in here ?
Links aren't working and it prints every animal I have in my database. Example:
I searched for animal named "Dog".
It prints all the right information for "Dog" but also information from "Cat" and "Mouse".

Comment: Your first problem is.... your **STILL** using mysql. You should **STOP** using it, and _any_ tutorial you are following showing it, should be ignored. Tutorials from anything more than a year ago, are probably outdated. The mysql function has been killed for a while, yet we still get 100s of questions here on SO including it..

Comment: Grammar correction: you are* ^

Comment: What's with the `print` in the middle of an `echo`? Otherwise, the OR condition matches ANY of the conditions you list. If any one of the conditions is empty, and you have matching empty fields for anything in your database, you would get the whole lot of them. Use AND instead, or better even, also only include the conditions that are specified.

Comment: @Ben Or `you're`. I didn't know this was an English board? Any code still containing the `mysql` functions should self-destruct. - Their print in the middle of the echo, with their broken joining of the variables, shows lack of experience programming in PHP, and the broken use of the HTML tags shows inexperience with HTML. ie: they are new, and wrote tons of broken stuff that doesn't make sense.

Comment: First get your query right, try running it in phpMyAdmin or a similiar querying tool. Then put the query into your PHP. Then parameterise it with the variables. Then all you need to do is fix the errors in the table building code

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. I will try these.

This might be stupid question but if I am not "allowed" to use mysql, what should I use ? I am studying to be programmer and we have used at school only mysql so I am little bit confused now =/

Comment: Markus AO: That `print` is supposed to print the searched animals name to the screen with a link to that animals own page. Of course, it's not doing it... Trying to figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr><td><a href=" . $row['name']> print $row['name'] . "</a>".
   "</td><td>" . $row['country'] . "</td></tr>". "</td><td>" . $row['sex']. "</td><td>" .
   $row['color']. "</td><td>". "</td><td>" .
    $row['pattern'] . $row['coat']. "</td><td>" . $row['breeders'];
   }
```

You have syntax problem near $row['name']

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `or` to be `and`.

And also, the sql query is not safe, it can be hacked easily.

change the line

`echo "<tr><td><a href=" . $row['name']> print $row['name'] . "</a>". "</td><td>" . $row['country'] . "</td></tr>". "</td><td>" . $row['sex']. "</td><td>" . $row['color']. "</td><td>". "</td><td>" . $row['pattern'] . $row['coat']. "</td><td>" . $row['breeders'];`

to be

`echo "<tr><td><a href='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td><td>{$row['country']}</td><td>{$row['sex']}</td><td>{$row['color']}</td><td>{$row['pattern']}</td><td>{$row['coat']}</td><td>{$row['breeders']}";`

and this line

`echo "</td></table>";`

to be

`echo "</td></tr></table>";`

Answer (score -1):

I will attempt to answer this, even though anything regarding *mysql* functions makes me sick. However, it isn't my job to re-code your script with mysqli or PDO functions, like they should be.

```
$sentence="SELECT `name`, `country`, `sex`, `color`, `pattern`, `coat`, `breeder` FROM `database` WHERE `name` = '$name' or `country` = '$country' or `sex` = '$sex' or `color` = '$color' or `pattern` = '$pattern' or `coat` = '$coat' or `breeder` = '$breeder'";
```

You said you searched for animal named "dog".. However you never told it to do that in your query.

Try this for your query:

```
$sentence = "SELECT name, country, sex, color, pattern, coat, breeder FROM database WHERE animal = 'dog' AND name = '$name' OR country = '$country' OR sex = '$sex' OR color = '$color' OR pattern = '$pattern' OR coat = '$coat' OR breeder = '$breeder'";
```

Your link is broken, because your code is broken. Try this:

```
    echo '<table>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $name = $row['name'];
    $country = $row['country'];
    $sex = $row['sex'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $pattern = $row['pattern'];
    $coat = $row['coat'];
    $breeders = $row['breeders'];

    echo "
        <tr>
            <td><a href=\"$name\">$name</a></td>
            <td>$country</td>
            <td>$sex</td>
            <td>$color</td>
            <td>$pattern</td>
            <td>$coat</td>
            <td>$breeders</td>
        </tr>";
}

echo '</table>';
```

I assigned everything to a variable, so we can place it in the code easier, and removed the extra `' . '` weird spacings. Your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags didn't match up either.. I would have to think your just learning, but you **must** match all your tags. A `<td>` must have a matching `</td>`, and they go in the same order they came in, not after other tags like `</tr>`. Your table spacing may be off now, but you can format it as you need, because I have no idea what your trying to make it look like, with broken tr and td's.

Comment: Leaving all those `OR's` in the query is going to return far more data than she probably wanted. It might be worth mentioning that as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree, but it isn't our job to teach them PHP. That is what books and courses are for. Since I can't see the variables coming in for `$country`, `$sex`, and the other variables, I don't know what they are trying to accomplish. I at least narrowed down her query to pull `dogs`. She indicated her two problems: It's not pulling just dogs, and the links are broken. I solved both of those with my answer.

Comment: I love the two downvote hit and runs. If you are going to downvote, leave a comment saying _why_ you down voted. Probably because they still think mysql is acceptable and I offended them..